# JavaScript prototype.constructor property for constructors not in spec?

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecmascript-5

I cannot find anywhere in the [JS spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) where functions - when called with `new` should set the `constructor` property of their prototype to themselves.

Sure the spec says the Built-in constructors (Object, Array, String, &c) all set their `prototype.constructor` properties to themselves (i.e. `Object.prototype.constructor = Object`) BUT I can't find anywhere that says this must/should happen for other constructors  (seems it should be spelled out in the `[[Construct]]` section (13.2.2 `[[Construct]]`) yet it is not:

```
function F() {};
var obj = new F();
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor == F;  // non-standard??  I can't find where in spec
```

I ask because I see a lot of code 'resetting' the prototype.constructor property of a constructor 'back' to itself - yet this appears to be non-standard that this property points back to the constructor function in the first place?

```
function F() {};
F.prototype = new Parent();
F.prototype.constructor = F;  // 'reset' it cuz it changed! (according to spec it should never have been set?  Except in Object.prototype.
```

Can/should JS programmers rely on this non-standard(?) expectation that a constructor's prototype.constructor property will point back to the constructor function itself if the prototype property is not set?

V8 certainly does this:

```
function F() {};
console.log(F.prototype.constructor === F); // true!  WHY???  not in spec?  Should be Object?
```

Hope that made vague sense - thanks!!
   Mark

PS Due to their mutability I would only rely on `instanceof` instead of using the `constructor` property.

Comment: I think best practice would be ditching constructors alltogether and using Object.create and .isPrototypeOf.

Comment: You are right, `[[construct]]` (the `new` keyword) does not set the constructor property. Instead, it is inherited from the default prototype object that is created with the function, have a look at [section 13.2](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2)

Comment: dun thanks~!!!  dunno how i missed that ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is standard for all functions to have a `.prototype` property that points to an object with a `.constructor` property that points back to the function.

[13.2 Creating Function objects](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2)

> 1) Create a new native ECMAScript object and let `F` be that object.
>
> ...
>
> 16) Let proto be the result of creating a new object as would be constructed by the expression `new Object()` where Object is the standard built-in constructor with that name.
>
> 17) Call the `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` internal method of proto with arguments `"constructor"`, Property Descriptor `{[[Value]]: F, { [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true}`, and false.
>
> 18) Call the `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` internal method of `F` with arguments `"prototype"`, Property Descriptor `{[[Value]]: proto, { [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false}`, and false.

So you can see `F` is the new function and `proto` is the prototype object. The `proto` gets a `"constructor"` property that points to `F`, and `F` gets a `"prototype"` property that points to the `proto` object

Comment: @user1883202: You're welcome, and FYI I just fixed the first sentence in my answer, which was poorly phrased.